# Specify cache validator and Leverage Browser caching with Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm trying to improve my websites speed and using GTMetrix for some analysis.
I'm getting 2 recommendations I cannot sort.

> Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
> ```
> https://cellfina.co.uk/favicon.ico (expiration not specified)
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1102/refill
> ```
>
> (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1103/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1104/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1108/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1109/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1110/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1111/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1291/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1432/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/881/refill
>   (expiration not specified)
>       https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PS6VCD5 (15 minutes)
>       https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/2069824809931530?v=2.8.47&r=stable
>   (20 minutes)
>       https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

and

> The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that
>   do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently.
>   Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for
>   the following resources:
>
> ```
> https://cellfina.co.uk/favicon.ico
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1102/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1103/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1104/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1108/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1109/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1110/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1111/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1291/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1432/refill
> https://cellfina.co.uk/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/881/refill
> https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/2069824809931530?v=2.8.47&r=stable
> ```

Within the `.htaccess` file I have

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```

which I would expect to deal with both the `js` and `favicon` files.

Why isn't it and how to I deal with the API calls?

Comment: What are the response headers for these resources? "which I would expect to deal with both" - mod_expires sets the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers, it doesn't do anything with `Last-Modified` or `ETag` headers (which are a _different_ caching mechanism). But that notice looks _advisory_, not necessarily mandatory? Do you even want those (JSON?) responses / API calls cached?

Comment: @DocRoot I would like the json calls cached because they return exactly the same info each time.  I don't know why the developer wrote it like that, but it is what I have.  Also, how should I set the `Last-Modified` and `ETag` for these items?